# Summation and deriving expressions for runtime

Tags: java, derived

I have the following code. I have to derive expressions for the runtime using summations, then solve them to obtain an expression for `T(n)` or `T(n,m)` that is not written with a summation. Then count how many times the `println` statement is executed as a function of any variables `n` and or `m`. `O()` is used to check answers.

```
T(n) E O(n)

for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
{
    System.out.println("hello");
}
```

I've got the summation part of this to get...

Sigma `i=0` lower bound, `n` is upper bound, and `println` is the constant.
From here, how do I solve this to get an expression for `T(n)`?

Here is another coding example of code where I found the summation but do not quite understand the second part of the question.

```
T(n) E O(n^2)
for (int i = 1; i <= n; ++i)
{
    for (int j = 1; j <= n; ++j)
    {
        System.out.println("Hello");
    }
}
```

Would like some help on the steps to go along with an answer.